# Sesame sawayaka udon

Tags: translation, food

I am interested in naming a dish “sesame sawayaka udon” in a restaurant in America, but am curious if this would sound silly to anyone who speaks Japanese.

Does it make sense in Japanese to use sawayaka to describe food (in particular udon) or the flavour of food?

Comment: This is opinion-based. Feel free to ask here: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or you could edit the question to be more fact-based. For instance, can "sawayaka" be used to describe food or the flavor of food?

Answer (score 5):

*Sawayaka* makes sense as a term to describe a dish. It means "refreshing", and so *sawayaka udon* sounds like it should be a light *udon* dish, for example with cold *udon* and cold broth (as often eaten on hot summer days), maybe with fresh grated ginger, or with raw vegetables like tomato or cucumber, or with other "fresh" flavours like citrus fruits (for example *kabosu*), etc.

But even *sawayaka udon nabe* could be possible for a warm (winter) dish, where *sawayaka* could refer to the "fresh" flavour of *yuzu*, say.